# Using JOIN in sql for two derived tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I have two separate queries, which I need to somehow merge into one set of results.

![This is Table 1, which shows the sum of each group's salary]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9F7I.png)

[image: This is output 2, which is the max value from table1]

Here is the queries I wrote to form the tables.

```
SELECT con_stagename, SUM(p_daily_salary) AS sum_salary
                FROM CONTENDER, PARTICIPANT
                WHERE p_contender = con_id
                GROUP BY con_id;
                
SELECT MAX(sum_salary) AS max_salary
FROM (SELECT con_stagename, SUM(p_daily_salary) AS sum_salary
                FROM CONTENDER, PARTICIPANT
                WHERE p_contender = con_id
                GROUP BY con_id) T2;
```

And the question is, if I want the result to be a single row of values, which the name of the group with the highest salary, and the actual amount. How would I do it? I've been trying to use JOIN operations but there was not luck.

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an explanation of the logic.  "Merge" is ambiguous.

Comment: "there was not luck" is not a problem description. What did you try, and why was it wrong?

Comment: The question is unclear [to me]. After an hour the OP hasn't added sample data or more information to clarify the question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT con_stagename, SUM(p_daily_salary) AS sum_salary
FROM CONTENDER, PARTICIPANT
WHERE p_contender = con_id
GROUP BY con_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```